# Store Facebook app referrer

Tags: php, ads, facebook-apps, http-referer

I have some Facebook ads and external ads pointing to an app which is sitting on a page tab.

When my app stores some user information, I'd like to also record which ad referred them to the app via some identifier.

I understand `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is unreliable in most cases, and any parameters passed as a query string (`http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-Page/21814976xxxxxxx?sk=app_25966185xxxxxxx&referrer=advert_1`) do not persist.

Is there a way I can accurately determine how a user got to my iframed Facebook app?

Dump of all HTTP request headers on the app:

```
[Host] => xxxxx.com.dev
[Connection] => keep-alive
[Content-Length] => 522
[Cache-Control] => max-age=0
[Origin] => http://static.ak.facebook.com
[User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1017.2 Safari/535.19
[Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
[Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[Referer] => http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4
[Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate,sdch
[Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
[Accept-Charset] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
[Cookie] => PHPSESSID=333dea05c7913f549c98599a797d4f71; __utma=75786053.945637676.1327581224.1327924758.1327928159.8; __utmb=75786053.2.10.1327928159; __utmc=75786053; __utmz=75786053.1327928159.8.8.utmcsr=static.ak.facebook.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/platform/page_proxy.php; fbsr_259661857422740=N5qiJMZV3Rx_oOpluV9fNfy76R98ux45MF9dqe8SFu4.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiIyLkFRQUU1eWRtcU1wWUlhMkYuMzYwMC4xMzI3OTMyMDAwLjUtMTgxOTA5OTAyMXxZZzNWY3ctdE52YVB1cjJQM3g2OFJBSVlnZEUiLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzMjc5MjgxNzYsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxODE5MDk5MDIxIn0; ci_session=a%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22ac29210xxxxxx8d1896cecdacc669%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A118%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Macintosh%3B+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_6_8%29+AppleWebKit%2F535.19+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F18.0.1017.2+Safari%2F535.19%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1327928158%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%22signed_request%22%3Bs%3A507%3A%22RBHppEnvz_GZwbPA74cZDbFyp3rYr8Tma8yorW3aoUA.eyJ[SNIPPED]%22%3B%7D72d0866c56330f1a75d00d53e44c6aa4
```

Comment: Removed by Facebook? Probably removed by the browser, because Facebook is not sending the HTTP referee but the browser is. Can you dump all request headers that are send to your server? Probably there is something available that you can make use of. It also would be good to add some value to your question.

Comment: Also take note that the correct spelling is `'HTTP_REFERER'` and not (as you wrote) `'HTTP_REFFERER'`. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `app_data` parameter to pass additional data to your application working in [Page Tab](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)

> In addition, your application will also receive a string parameter called `app_data` as part of `signed_request` if an `app_data` parameter was set in the original query string in the URL your tab is loaded on. For the Shop Now link above, that could look like this: "http://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here". You can use that to customize the content you render if you control the generation of the link.